# Is there a simple way to filter & narrow collections on instance type in assertj?

Tags: assertj

Can this be written as a single line?

```
assertThat(actualDeltas)
        .filteredOn(delta -> delta instanceof Replacement)
        .asInstanceOf(InstanceOfAssertFactories.list(Replacement.class))
```

I expected asInstanceOf to do the filtering. Alternatively, I searched for extractors or other concepts, but couldn't find any simple solution.

Is that possible with `assertj`?

Comment: Could you enhance the example to show the kind of assertion you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

By design, the purpose of `asInstanceOf` is only to provide type-narrowed assertions for cases where the type of the object under assertion is not visible at compile time.

When you provide `InstanceOfAssertFactories.list(Replacement.class)` as a parameter for `asInstanceOf`, you are telling AssertJ that you *expect* the object under assertion to be a `List` with elements of type `Replacement`.

While `asInstanceOf` will make sure that the object under test is a `List`, it will neither filter nor enforce that all the list elements are of type `Replacement`. The `Replacement` will ensure type-safety with subsequent methods that can be chained, for example with [extracting(Function)](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#extracting(java.util.function.Function)).

Currently, `filteredOn(Predicate)` or any other `filteredOn` variant is the right way to take out elements that should not be part of the assertion. If the filtering would happen outside (e.g., via Stream API), no `asInstanceOf` call would be needed as `assertThat()` could detect the proper element type based on the input declaration.

Comment: Sure, but is there no way to filter based on type + cast to that exact same time with assertj, with a single operation?

Comment: Not at the moment, and the recommendation would still be to use `filteredOn` and `asInstanceOf` together. However, having more details about the concrete use case could help reconsider the topic, ideally in an issue at https://github.com/assertj/assertj-core/issues/new.